# Pull only the new data from biometric device + zkemkeeper

Tags: c#, fingerprint, biometrics

I have successfully connected  to the biometric device and able to pull all records using Zkemkeeper.dll by using the following method

```
axCZKEM1.ReadGeneralLogData(iMachineNumber)
```

By using the above method every time it will pull all the datas present at a particular time in the device.

But i want to get the newly inserted data everytime. Is it possible in Zkemkeeper, if not is any best way to accomplish this? Plz share ur ideas. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

ReadGeneralLogData is meant for loading all the attendance logs. For getting the newly registered you have to register the event with RegEvent api provided in the dll file you have.

Signature of the RegEvent

> VARIANT_BOOL RegEvent( [in] LONG dwMachineNumber, [in] LONG EventMask)
>   dwMachineNumber is zero
>   EventMask is 1

Once registered, the OnAttTransactionEx event will be called every time a attendance gets registered.

The event signature is

> OnAttTransactionEx (BSTR EnrollNumber,LONG IsInValid,LONG AttState, LONG
>   VerifyMethod,LONG Year, LONG Month, LONG Day, LONG Hour, LONG Minute, LONG Second,
>   LONG WorkCode)

If you are looking for the WebApi support, the you can refer [http://camsunit.com/application/biometric-web-api.html](http://www.etscouncil.com/login?mailerResponse=true&orn=stackoverflow&ts=04/08/2017&ornr="https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44258751/pull-only-the-new-data-from-biometric-device-zkemkeeper/"&tpc=CAMS&it=CAMS-API&learnref=http://camsunit.com/application/biometric-web-api.html)

Comment: Thanks. But im using essl f18 model , my vendor said that this hardware will not support real time event..

Comment: Are you sure, if your vendor is the technical people. They may a reseller. They may be knowing about the hardware troubleshooting. Beyond then, They would not know how the software works. So, i like to suggest you to double check your conclusion.

Comment: Actually i tried to register the event using `OnAttTransactionEx` my device is totally blocked, then i concluded that its not possible..

Comment: Ok. it is surprising. If you are looking for buying more machines then you can chose the similar one called RSP10t from http://camsunit.com/product/cams-access-control-systems.html

This supports the OnAttTransactionEx event.

Answer (score 1):

> *But im using essl f18 model , my vendor said that this hardware will not support real time event*

^This is what made me write my answer, it does support real time event. As I have done it myself with the F-18 series.

Continuing from what what Ramshri's answer, there are two ways to achieve what you want.

1: Through registering the real time events

2: Get all the data that you already are from the machine and then refactor to only what you need.

First Approach:

```
public int sta_RegRealTime(ListBox lblOutputInfo)
        {
            if (GetConnectState() == false)
            {
                lblOutputInfo.Items.Add("*Please connect first!");
                return -1024;
            }

            int ret = 0;

            if (axCZKEM1.RegEvent(GetMachineNumber(), 65535))//Here you can register the realtime events that you want to be triggered(the parameters 65535 means registering all)
            {
                //common interface
                this.axCZKEM1.OnFinger += new zkemkeeper._IZKEMEvents_OnFingerEventHandler(axCZKEM1_OnFinger);
                this.axCZKEM1.OnVerify += new zkemkeeper._IZKEMEvents_OnVerifyEventHandler(axCZKEM1_OnVerify);
                this.axCZKEM1.OnFingerFeature += new zkemkeeper._IZKEMEvents_OnFingerFeatureEventHandler(axCZKEM1_OnFingerFeature);
                this.axCZKEM1.OnDeleteTemplate += new zkemkeeper._IZKEMEvents_OnDeleteTemplateEventHandler(axCZKEM1_OnDeleteTemplate);
                this.axCZKEM1.OnNewUser += new zkemkeeper._IZKEMEvents_OnNewUserEventHandler(axCZKEM1_OnNewUser);
                this.axCZKEM1.OnHIDNum += new zkemkeeper._IZKEMEvents_OnHIDNumEventHandler(axCZKEM1_OnHIDNum);
                this.axCZKEM1.OnAlarm += new zkemkeeper._IZKEMEvents_OnAlarmEventHandler(axCZKEM1_OnAlarm);
                this.axCZKEM1.OnDoor += new zkemkeeper._IZKEMEvents_OnDoorEventHandler(axCZKEM1_OnDoor);

                //only for color device
                this.axCZKEM1.OnAttTransactionEx += new zkemkeeper._IZKEMEvents_OnAttTransactionExEventHandler(axCZKEM1_OnAttTransactionEx);
                this.axCZKEM1.OnEnrollFingerEx += new zkemkeeper._IZKEMEvents_OnEnrollFingerExEventHandler(axCZKEM1_OnEnrollFingerEx);

                //only for black&white device
                this.axCZKEM1.OnAttTransaction -= new zkemkeeper._IZKEMEvents_OnAttTransactionEventHandler(axCZKEM1_OnAttTransaction);
                this.axCZKEM1.OnWriteCard += new zkemkeeper._IZKEMEvents_OnWriteCardEventHandler(axCZKEM1_OnWriteCard);
                this.axCZKEM1.OnEmptyCard += new zkemkeeper._IZKEMEvents_OnEmptyCardEventHandler(axCZKEM1_OnEmptyCard);
                this.axCZKEM1.OnKeyPress += new zkemkeeper._IZKEMEvents_OnKeyPressEventHandler(axCZKEM1_OnKeyPress);
                this.axCZKEM1.OnEnrollFinger += new zkemkeeper._IZKEMEvents_OnEnrollFingerEventHandler(axCZKEM1_OnEnrollFinger);


                ret = 1;
            }
            else
            {
                axCZKEM1.GetLastError(ref idwErrorCode);
                ret = idwErrorCode;

                if (idwErrorCode != 0)
                {
                    lblOutputInfo.Items.Add("*RegEvent failed,ErrorCode: " + idwErrorCode.ToString());
                }
                else
                {
                    lblOutputInfo.Items.Add("*No data from terminal returns!");
                }
            }
            return ret;
        }
```

and their definitions:

```
 //If your fingerprint(or your card) passes the verification,this event will be triggered,only for color device
        void axCZKEM1_OnAttTransactionEx(string EnrollNumber, int IsInValid, int AttState, int VerifyMethod, int Year, int Month, int Day, int Hour, int Minute, int Second, int WorkCode)
        {
            string time = Year + "-" + Month + "-" + Day + " " + Hour + ":" + Minute + ":" + Second;

            gRealEventListBox.Items.Add("Verify OK.UserID=" + EnrollNumber + " isInvalid=" + IsInValid.ToString() + " state=" + AttState.ToString() + " verifystyle=" + VerifyMethod.ToString() + " time=" + time);

            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        //If your fingerprint(or your card) passes the verification,this event will be triggered,only for black%white device
        private void axCZKEM1_OnAttTransaction(int EnrollNumber, int IsInValid, int AttState, int VerifyMethod, int Year, int Month, int Day, int Hour, int Minute, int Second)
        {
            string time = Year + "-" + Month + "-" + Day + " " + Hour + ":" + Minute + ":" + Second;
            gRealEventListBox.Items.Add("Verify OK.UserID=" + EnrollNumber.ToString() + " isInvalid=" + IsInValid.ToString() + " state=" + AttState.ToString() + " verifystyle=" + VerifyMethod.ToString() + " time=" + time);

            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        //After you have placed your finger on the sensor(or swipe your card to the device),this event will be triggered.
        //If you passes the verification,the returned value userid will be the user enrollnumber,or else the value will be -1;
        void axCZKEM1_OnVerify(int UserID)
        {
            if (UserID != -1)
            {
                gRealEventListBox.Items.Add("User fingerprint verified... UserID=" + UserID.ToString());
            }
            else
            {
                gRealEventListBox.Items.Add("Failed to verify... ");
            }

            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
```

Second Approach:
Now let's assume you have fetched all the data but you only require the data *after the one* you fetched from last time. Taking an example like; you need to store the updated data to your dB everytime you call the `axCZKEM1.ReadGeneralLogData(iMachineNumber);`
Compare the return listData with the one in your dB (with `DateTime column` since it will act as a unique one in the table) like;

```
ICollection<AttendanceLog> lstMachineInfo = manipulator.GetLogData(objZkeeper2, machineNum);
        if (lstMachineInfo != null && lstMachineInfo.Count > 0)
        {
            var lastRecord = db.yourTableNameHere.OrderByDescending(x => x.DateTime).FirstOrDefault();


            if (lastRecord != null)
            {
                lstMachineInfo = lstMachineInfo.Where(x => x.DateTime > lastRecord.DateTime).ToList();
            }

            foreach (var p in lstMachineInfo)
            {
                db.yourTableNameHere.Add(p);
            }

            db.SaveChanges();
```

Using the First Approach:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

To do what you want to do, you can follow this steps:

1. Get all the log data from the device (and save it to a database).
2. Delete all the log data from the device (use function `ClearGLog()`).

By doing this, every time you fetch the attendance log you'll get the newest.
You could try to get the real time event for every time someone enters, but you'll miss the ones that are registered when the computer is not on. If you don't want to miss any attendance log you should do this.
Also, you should disable the device before you fetch the log data and enable it after you delete it from the device. You can do this with the `EnableDevice(machineNumber, 1=enable | 0=disable)`.